# Choosing the correct google cloud data storage strategy for images

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm writing my first google cloud backend for an image sharing mobile app and I'm having difficulties understanding which data storage option to go for. The clients will be mobile apps and probably also a web frontend. From what I've read so far the AppEngine seems to be a nice infrastructure for this.

I need to handle:

- *Users*
- *Groups of users*
- *Collections of images* (created within a group of user, many shared with all users )
- The actual *image files*
- Start small but with an architecture able to support massive upscaling (in terms of users and images)

Would it make sense to store the actual *images* in Cloud Storage and the metadata about *users*, *Groups of users* and *Collections of images* in Datastore or MySql? In particular I'm having trouble choosing betwween Datastore and MySql.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, I have very little experience from databases :)

Cheers!

Comment: You are asking for an opinion about a use case we know little about. Both options are good but depends on many details. Sorry but s.o. is not the right place for this. You need to read quite a bit about both options before you can choose. There are many articles written about this topic of sql vs nosql. Come back with a specific question about it.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Zig. Ok never mind the difference between Datastore and MySql. Lets narrow down the question to: Is it a good approach to store the actual image files in Cloud Storage and all other information about users, groups, etc in Datastore or MySql? (I'll read up on sql vs nosql).

Comment: Yes its the best option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Images (or other big "opaque" goobs of data such as video) on Cloud Storage, and metadata about them in a more structured store, is the classic architecture pattern for all similar use cases.

If you need some features of relational databases, such as `JOIN`s, on your metadata, then Cloud SQL may be what you need for the "more structured store"; however since you're designing from scratch it's usually quite feasible to use a NoSQL store like App Engine's Datastore, with scalability and other advantages pertaining to it (and you **do** mention "massive upscaling" in the future, so this may be quite relevant to you!-).

Among the advantages of this classic architecture is that object stores like Cloud Storage can give you "serving URLs" to specific objects (images) that you can pass to clients so that the serving of such massive data will be done by Cloud Storage's own servers, without burdening your application's servers.  Moreover, as https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/website-configuration puts it,

> Google Cloud Storage behaves essentially like a Content Delivery
>   Network (CDN) with no work on your part because publicly readable
>   objects are, by default, cached in the Google Cloud Storage network.

so at least for images that are "shared with all" (and thus you can mark as publicly readable) you'll get a CDN's advantages of low latency "with no work on your part".

Comment: @Aardvarklord, always HTH, but remember to **accept** the answer (clic on the checkmark outline shape on its upper left)...!